Cannot find module '@...' when building Angular app
I am working on an Angular app that I recently upgraded from v14 to v17. I have been working to get packages, config, etc. all setup to run correctly with this. Somewhere along the way, something caused my custom file paths / modules to not work upon build.
I can see upon hovering that it is getting correctly resolved:

However, I receive the following error upon building my project via npm build
Error: libs/utilities/src/lib/tools/monitorable-tools.ts:2:102 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@icm/models' or its corresponding type declarations.

2     IsOrganization, MonitorableIcon, DeviceType, MonitorableType, PauseType, SubscriptionType } from '@icm/models';

My tsconfig.json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "typeRoots": ["./types", "node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["ES2022", "dom"],
    "paths": {
      "@icm/account": ["libs/account/src/index.ts"],
      "@icm/charts": ["libs/charts/src/index.ts"],
      "@icm/core": ["libs/core/src/index.ts"],
      "@icm/internal": ["libs/internal/src/index.ts"],
      "@icm/models": ["libs/models/src/index.ts"],
      "@icm/monitorables": ["libs/monitorables/src/index.ts"],
      "@icm/probe-registration": ["libs/probe-registration/src/index.ts"],
      "@icm/templating": ["libs/monitorables/src/lib/templating/index.ts"],
      "@icm/tour": ["libs/tour/src/index.ts"],
      "@icm/ui": ["libs/ui/src/index.ts"],
      "@icm/utilities": ["libs/utilities/src/index.ts"],
      "@icm/wizard": ["libs/wizard/src/index.ts"],
      "@tools/testing": ["tools/testing/index.ts"]
    },
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictTemplate": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "styles/**", "assets/**"]
}


